# Anonymous Authentication in IIS over https does not fire a postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, https, iis-7.5

I recently decided to change from using Windows Authentication for my internal web applications to Forms Authentication. I've not used the latter very much and one site explained you have to enable both Forms and Anonymous for this to work. The idea is to verify user passwords against an active directory then grant them access accordingly. I had this working just fine locally and when publishing to IIS 7.5 it still worked. It was just a basic Visual Studio project that would redirect to our homepage.

The problems arose when I tried accessing this same project securely with https, I included the full domain and it would load the new login page but when I clicked login it would do nothing. Since then I've scoured the web and found numerous mentions of this and that and tried many of them to no avail.

It was only later I created a blank project with a single button and one line of the code on the page to see if a post back had fired. After publishing I only enabled Anonymous Authentication in IIS and browsing to this basic test app using http when you clicked the button, false on the page changed to true - indicating a post back. Yet with https it just remains false. I think this may be why the active directory login wasn't working as it too had Anonymous enabled.

I'm still pretty new at the secure side of things but with the details passing over I have to use a secure connection just for the login then it can redirect to the usual applications we use internally.

I'd appreciate any thoughts you may have regarding this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We use this configuration (anonymous IIS access, forms authentication, and https) successfully all of the time.

There are three things that you should do to track this issue down:

1) Verify that there are no javascript errors in the page that break the button (i.e. a javascript file not being delivered to the page)

2) Check the windows event logs for exceptions from asp.net/iis.

3) Install and run [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com), select `Fiddler Options...` from the `Tools` menu, click on the `HTTPS` tab and ensure all of the checkboxes are checked, then run your website and look at the requests and responses, particularly when you press the button.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions competent_tech I tried a bunch of things and had it working for a while but then it stopped again. I'm going to stick with Windows Auth just now but in future will delve into this again as the latter isn't ideal for every situation.